# Deploy Nuxt 3 build folder with express server

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

How can I deploy Nuxt 3 `.output` folder to `expressjs` server? As like `vuejs` or `reactjs` build folder has `index.html` and all other files included, so in `express` we can just serve/render the `build` folder as static file. But, what about Nuxt 3? in the `.output` folder I can see a new `Nodejs` server like folder structure.

Comment: Which command are you using to build? `npm build` or `npm generate` ? Can you share some code?